# How can I use Shaka Player with raw mp4 video data arriving over xhr or websocket?

Tags: javascript, media-source, fmp4

I know how can I give [Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) a file or mpd from the internet to playback.

However, how can I push raw data from client side JavaScript to it? I could not find anything for that, maybe it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can't. When you feed Shaka Player a .mpd file you give the player choose which resolution to use, eventually where to seek etc. All these options imply *actions* that will be taken by the player, and these actions take the form of a GET requests depending upon what it finds inside the .mpd file.

If you open a websocket and push data all this does not make sense.

Comment: "how can I push raw data from client side JavaScript to it?"

Answer (score 0):

easiest way would be checking server time-to-time:

```
setInterval(checkServer, 5000);
function checkServer(){
  fetch('myurl').then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>switch(r.cmd){
     case 'play': player.url = r.url;
     break;
  })
}
```

server should respond as json {cmd:'play', url:'/video.vp8'}

If you can dig websocket, server can **send** command.